# How to extend folder location on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, server, location

I am getting error while compiling site configuration:

```
location ~ /la(.*) {}

location /la {}
```

```
nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: nothing to repeat in "/la(*.)" at "*.)"
```

I need to urls like /las-Vegas works on first location, and links like /la/title on second. I have tried use quotes in regex, but this won’t help. Maybe some other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config file `~ /la(*.) {}` is set mistakainly. Change it to:

```
~ /la(.*) {}
```

Comment: There is no mistake, I set is identically to you. But it still not working. When I set second location to /la/ it stops working and I get error File not found from nginx

Comment: Error says you put * before dot. The order should be changed.